# Django doesn't update HTML template after `model.save()`

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application using Django REST Framework. When I do an Ajax call that changes a model field:

```py
# Delete media
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
    media = get_object_or_404(Media, pk=pk)
    media.deleted = True
    media.save()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and then trigger a JavaScript `location.reload();`, the reloaded page still contain the "deleted" model. On the database the `deleted` field is True, and on my template I make this:

```html
{% for media in issue.getMedia %}
    {% if not media.deleted %}
        {% include 'core2/include/media.html' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I reload the Django webserver it no longer shows the `media.deleted` objects.

### Edited

The Ajax request is:

```
controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.execute = function(url){
                console.log($scope.action)

                $.ajax({
                    url: $scope.action,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    success: function(result){
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        alert("Error deleting")
                        console.log(e)
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

When I modify the objects using a regular Django form (for example when create an object), the page reloads properly.

### Edition 2

The implementation of the `issue.getMedia` on the issue model:

```py
    def getMedia(self):
        return Media.objects.filter(issue=self).order_by('creationDate')
```

Comment: Are you sure the reload works?

Comment: Any Idea? Maybe is because I don't update the serializers...?

Comment: We will need to check if the ajax call is working or not. I suspect that field status is not changed in the database. There is no issue with rending. 
Can you, make the delete API call, and then check the value of deleted in the database?

Comment: @sun_jara the field change on the database properly. So, I push the button to make the ajax call, I debug the call on backend and on the database (everything work properly), and then I reload the frontend page, cleaning also the cache, without success. Only if I restart the django framework it reload correctly the model

Comment: Understood. Can you share the implementation of `issue.getMedia` and also get_context() method where you are setting the value of issue context variable.  Also, are you using prefetch_related anywhere?

Comment: I have tried with  with firefox and it just work fine. Can you share your template code ?

Comment: Making an AJAX request just to reload the page after receiving AJAX response doesn't make any sense in the first place.

Comment: Hi. @ElmoVanKielmo reload the page should update  the list of "medias" and I don't want do it via Javascript.  As I said on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888645/django-doesnt-update-html-template-after-model-save?noredirect=1#comment96660163_54946342) if I change to a firefox private window the model is shown updated. @sun_jara I don't use `prefetch_related` and I edited putting the info about `issue.getMedia` implementation. Where should I find `get_context()` function? I tried to grep -rn the project looking for it without success

Comment: Since you're not rendering deleted objects, why not just `.exclude(deleted=True)` from `getMedia`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the "never_cache" decorator to the view reponsible for page rendering:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request, ...):
   ...
```

or to the dispatch method if it's a CBV:

```
class MyView(View):

    @never_cache
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: It works! Could you explain what are the consequences to disable cache? Slower page rendering?

Comment: Using "never_cache" decorator, you instruct the browser not to cache the page, so whenever the user requires it, he's browser will in turn hit the server (which, by the way, is exactly what you want in your use case).
How much latency this adds depends on the work required to rebuild the specific page. I wouldn't be obsessed too much with caching in a dynamic site, until there is an evidence that too many users are requiring the same page. In that case, I would consider caching as a measure to reduce resources usage on the server - but before that I would try to optimize the page rendering.

Comment: Having said this, I'm afraid the user will notice the page reload; caching is not an option here, as you've already experienced, but you have more solutions available.
For example, you could avoid altogether the page reload, and instead remove the deleted item from the existing page with DOM manipulation. 
This can be safely triggered by the successfull return from the ajax call, which is an evidence that the object has already been deleted on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use `location.reload(true)`. Maybe it takes page from cash.

Comment: @selan - I still think, that problem is in reload. What do you mean `I clean also the cache manually for each reload`?

Comment: mm.. I realize that if I open the page on a private window the model appears updated, instead on the old window (firefox) still appear the old one. I use firefox, to reload the content I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> that should clear the cache. Also I have the `disable cache` option on developer tools > network.